# Geoserver rendering & GPU

Tags: geoserver, hardware

Would a nice GPU on the Geoserver server (let's pretend it's old school housing) help in any way, or make any difference at all with the rendering tasks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, GeoServer does not use the GPU.

Comment: While this is probably correct, could you add sources ?

Comment: It's too much work to prove a negative, sorry.